# Searching data; integer to string issue

Tags: javascript, integer

I am trying to search through the data but because the IMF field is an integer I get an error when searching that field. How do I convert just that line to a string in the entire array? If I manual change every object IMF field to a string it works. When I try to JSON.stringify(jsonData) it converts everything into a different string issue and my data is undefined. It just seems to stringify the entire set of objects.

JSON.stringify

```
"[{'imf':6546,'description':'DEXTROSE-5%-INJ-250ML','group':'C4PV','vendor':'MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG','vsn':'BHL2B0062QH'},{'imf':6546,'description':'GLYCINE-1.5%-IRR-3000ML','group':'A4PV','vendor':'MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG','vsn':'BHL2B7317'},{'imf':6546,'description':'SET,GRAVITY,10 DROPS/ML','group':'A4PV','vendor':'MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG','vsn':'IME42493EH'},{'imf':465465,'description':'DEXTROSE-5%-INJ-250ML','group':'C4PV','vendor':'MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG','vsn':'BHL2B0062QH'},{'imf':1546,'description':'GLYCINE-1.5%-IRR-3000ML','group':'A4PV','vendor':'MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG','vsn':'BHL2B7317'},{'imf':2654,'description':'SET,GRAVITY,10 DROPS/ML','group':'A4PV','vendor':'MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG','vsn':'IME42493EH'}]"
```

```js
var codesEl;
var jsonData = [
 {
            "imf": 6546,
            "description": "DEXTROSE-5%-INJ-250ML",
            "group": "C4PV",
            "vendor": "MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG",
            "vsn": "BHL2B0062QH"
        },
        {
            "imf": 6546,
            "description": "GLYCINE-1.5%-IRR-3000ML",
            "group": "A4PV",
            "vendor": "MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG",
            "vsn": "BHL2B7317"
        },
        {
            "imf": 6546,
            "description": "SET,GRAVITY,10 DROPS/ML",
            "group": "A4PV",
            "vendor": "MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG",
            "vsn": "IME42493EH"
        },
   {
            "imf": 465465,
            "description": "DEXTROSE-5%-INJ-250ML",
            "group": "C4PV",
            "vendor": "MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG",
            "vsn": "BHL2B0062QH"
        },
        {
            "imf": 1546,
            "description": "GLYCINE-1.5%-IRR-3000ML",
            "group": "A4PV",
            "vendor": "MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG",
            "vsn": "BHL2B7317"
        },
        {
            "imf": 2654,
            "description": "SET,GRAVITY,10 DROPS/ML",
            "group": "A4PV",
            "vendor": "MEDLINE INDUSTRIES, INC. MSPV-NG",
            "vsn": "IME42493EH"
        }
];

function printData(Arr) {
  for(var i=0; i<Arr.length; i++) {
    codesEl.innerText += `\n IMF: ${Arr[i].imf} Description: ${Arr[i].description} Group: ${Arr[i].group} Vendor: ${Arr[i].vendor} Stock: ${Arr[i].vsn}`;
    console.log(Arr)
  }
}

// it is a case insensitive search
function search(ev) {
  var key = ev.target.value;
  codesEl.innerText = null;
  
  printData(jsonData.filter((data)=>{
    var regex = new RegExp(key, "i");
    return data.imf.match(regex) || data.description.match(regex) || data.group.match(regex) || data.vendor.match(regex) || data.vsn.match(regex);
  }));
}

window.onload = function() {
  codesEl = document.getElementById("codes");
  printData(jsonData);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="search(event)" placeholder="Enter Search Key Here" />
<div>
  <span id="codes"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `data.imf.match(regex)` won't work because numbers don't have a match method. try `String(data.imf).match(regex)`  or `regex.test(data.imf)` instead. you should also move the regexp creation out of the filter function as well; there's no reason to make a new one each time, and many reasons not to. it would also be better to pass the value  `onkeyup="search(value)"`  and `function search(key)` instead of dom nodes.

Comment: Note that JSON is a text format; the variable named `jsonData` is an array of objects; nothing to do with JSON. You may have originally gotten the data as JSON over HTTP or a file system, but once you're running things like `filter` on it, it's no longer JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all the values to string

```
function search(ev) {
  var key = ev.target.value;
  codesEl.innerText = null;
  
  printData(jsonData.filter((data)=>{
    var regex = new RegExp(key, "i");
    // Here cast all the val to strings
    return Object.values(data).some(val => String(val).match(regex);
  }));
}
```